# not getting inside value of id through (java script)

Tags: php, regex

i want only values inside my ISBN through my HTML Code

```
<div ISBN="9381015889">
```

Java Script Code

`($("#ISBN").val());`
i am not getting value of ISBN=9381015889

Comment: What are you trying to do? Assigning your custom selector to jQuery. You have to change your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get this by using `jquery` `data`

**HTML**

```
<div data-ISBN="9381015889" id="ISBN">
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#ISBN").data('ISBN');
```

Comment: i have content like this   <div ISBN="9381015889"> not like this <div data-ISBN="9381015889" id="ISBN">

Comment: I think there is no way to get this data. You have to change your HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Put id attribute in the html div. ISBN cannot be attribute. So make `id` as attribute and name it as ISBN like below.

```
<div id="ISBN">9381015889</div>
```

Use this to access

```
$("#ISBN").html();
```

as `.val()` is used if you want to take from form fields like text field or drop down.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to specify an ID to the div.:

```
<div id="ISBN" data-isbn="9381015889">
```

You can access the ISBN number via:
 `$("#ISBN").data("isbn")` 
Reff: [Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
alert($(this).attr('ISBN'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML**

```
<div ISBN="9381015889" id="ISBN">
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#ISBN").attr('ISBN');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user data-ISBN instead of plain ISBN and include an **id** attribute for **div tag**

Then you can retrieve it using javacript like this

```
<div id='isbndata' data-ISBN="9381015889">

var selector= document.querySelector('#isbndata');

alert('Info is :' + selector.dataset.ISBN);
```

You can also use jquery's data attribute:

```
$('#isbndata').data('ISBN');
```

Links which can be helpful to u

http://api.jquery.com/data/
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying the html code, the css selector can be adapted: `div[ISBN]` instead of `#ISBN`.

Try this snippet:

```js
document.write( $('div[ISBN]').attr('ISBN') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ISBN="9381015889">
```